# Threads within C++ class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I used to code on C++ long ago, but now decided to recall old skills and achieve some new ones :D

For now I am trying to rewrite my C# program in C++ and one problem occured - I don't know how to manage threads, or even how to create them, using class methods and calling methods from the class.

```
class MyObj {
private:
    void thread() {
        while (true) {
            std::string a;
            cin >> a;
        }
    }

    static DWORD static_entry(LPVOID* param) {
        MyObj *myObj = (MyObj*)param;
        myObj->thread();
        return 0;
    }

public:
    void start() {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)static_entry, this, 0, NULL);
    }
};
```

That is sample, I've found here, on StackOverflow but 'void thread()' was empty function, I've added code, given above, but the thread seems to start and close immediately.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using `std::thread`?

Comment: It's probably better to use `std::thread` as a member of your class.

Comment: Never cast a function pointer to a different type.

Comment: no actual reasons, I am just running CLI, it has problems with including <thread>
I'll give it a try and give the response asap
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I've added code, given above, but the thread seems to start and close immediately.

That's because you don't wait for threads to finish in your main thread.

As from their [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll need to add something like

```
// Wait until all threads have terminated. 
WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

For `std::thread` this should be a call to `std::thread::join()`.

---

I'd rather recommend using `std::thread` as a member of the `MyObj` class:

```
class MyObj {
private:
    void thread_fn() {
        while (true) {
            std::string a;
            cin >> a;
        }
    }

    std::thread t;

public:
    void start() {
        t = std::thread(&MyObj::thread_fn,*this);
    }
    ~MyObj() {
       if(t.joinable())
           t.join();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.
Using *std::thread* turned out to be easier than using CLI Tread class.

```
static void input() {
    while (true) {
        std::string a;
        cin >> a;
        secureProg::execute_command(a);
    }
}

auto start() {
    std::thread thread(secureProg::input);
    thread.join();  
    return thread.get_id();
}
```

Thread start from *main*

```
secureProg a;
    auto thread_ptr = a.start();
```

Final version (I hope) of two methods within class

Comment: It's arguable if you should call `join()`  from `start()` or rather use a destructor call of a class (`secureProg`) that encapsulates that stuff.

Comment: as for now it works, if something occurs later, I will try to rewrite this.
now I am searching how to interrupt/suspend std::thread ._.

Comment: The problem is that `return thread.get_id();` will provide the thread id after it was executed in whole. That's most probably not what you want.